# Search exact string in a file

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.x

I am using the below if condition and regular expression to search for an IP address in a file,It will search for the IP address that has the space at the end for example: 192.168.x.x , however it is not searching for the IP address which is present in this format 192.168.x.x/32 because it does not have the space at the end, it has a "/" character

How can i modify the search condition to include both the variations in the output

```
if (re.match('(.+) '  +host_ipaddress+  ' (.+)', line)):
```

Comment: `192.168.x.x(\/\d+)?` ?

Comment: @Dave host_ipaddress is a user input, i took 192.168.x.x as an example and the number of digits per octet can vary like 172.16.0.0 or 10.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (re.match('(.+) '  +host_ipaddress+  '(\/\d+) (.+)', line)):
```

or

```
if (re.match('(.+) '  +host_ipaddress+  '(\/\d{1,2}) (.+)', line)):
```

if you want to be more precise.

Though ideally, you shouldn't need to require `(.+)` and the beginning or end of your expression.